# Replacing null values in dynamic pivot sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

[image]

Image transcription:

```
FTE/RATE CARD | 2018-01-01 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-03-01 | 2018-04-01 | 2018-05-01 | 2018-06-01 | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FTE 3         | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | 33         | 38         | 40.5       | ...
```

I have a pivot sql query as below.
I need to replace NULL values with Zeros in the result.
I don't know where do I exactly use the IsNull or Coalesce function in the query.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT  @cols = STUFF
(
(
SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH])
FROM   [HEADCOUNT]
WHERE  [MONTH] BETWEEN '01-012018' AND '12-01-2018'
ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH])
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''
)
SET     @query = 'SELECT [FTE/RATE CARD],' + @cols + ' FROM
(
SELECT  [MONTH],[FTE/RATE CARD],[HC]
FROM    [HEADCOUNT]
WHERE   [CC-LOC] IN ([CC-LOC]) 

) x pivot (Sum ([HC]) for [MONTH] in (' + @cols + '))p' execute(@query)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: That isn't an RDBMS @Khushal_Jain, that's an application. But it does answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to generate another column list for the select statement, and wrap individual months with ISNULL, like so:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @selectCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SELECT  @selectCols = STUFF
(
(
SELECT distinct ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([MONTH]) + ', 0) AS ' + QUOTENAME([MONTH])
FROM   [HEADCOUNT]
WHERE  [MONTH] BETWEEN '01-012018' AND '12-01-2018'
ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH])
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''
)



SELECT  @cols = STUFF
(
(
SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH])
FROM   [HEADCOUNT]
WHERE  [MONTH] BETWEEN '01-012018' AND '12-01-2018'
ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH])
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''
)
SET     @query = 'SELECT [FTE/RATE CARD],' + @selectCols + ' FROM
(
SELECT  [MONTH],[FTE/RATE CARD],[HC]
FROM    [HEADCOUNT]
WHERE   [CC-LOC] IN ([CC-LOC]) 

) x pivot (Sum ([HC]) for [MONTH] in (' + @cols + '))p' execute(@query)
```

Comment: Yet, I'm getting the same result!

Comment: @Khushal_Jain Right, it's because of the missing records for these months. See my edited answer, you need to wrap the select columns in `ISNULL`.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinJ but now I'm getting an rror as below -

Comment: 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Khushal_Jain That's why mentioning the database version is important, `CONCAT` was introduced in SQL Server 2012 and you're probably using 2005 or 2008. I edited my answer to replace its usage with concatenation using + operator.

Comment: Yea, thanks, you're correct I'm using SQL 2008..! I'll check the code you gave and run it again.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinJ , The updated query did work, only I had to remove "ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH]) DESC" the clause from the selectCols code declaration

Comment: @Khushal_Jain If it works for you, consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer so that users who visit this question in the future know it worked.